# partition not showing on partition manager

Tags: filesystems, partition

My 1TB hard disk has two partitions, namely sda1 and sda2. Although sda1 is showing on partition manager, sda2 is not.
I accidently unmounted the sda2 partition and then had to mount it on a folder named mnt in the root directory. If I mount it on the media folder only the sda1 I mean the "New Volume"(name of the partition) shows. Though I can access the contents on the sda2 via accessing in the mnt folder, my file system does not show it in the device section and partition manager cannot find it.
To note, both sda1 and sda2 are ntfs file system. And I cannot afford to format the data in sda2, because they are very important.

Not to mention, I use MX-linux kde version. Here I am attaching the images of the partition manager and fstab file.
[image: partition manager]

[image: contents of fstab]

Comment: Partition 1 seems to span the entire disk. Use command line tools to confirm, such as `lsblk`, `fdisk -l`, `parted /dev/sda print`. Also, are you able to mount sda2 or not? Your description is not quite clear.

Comment: I could sort out the issue partially. The main problem was that both partitions were ntfs based partition. So I had to mount them using ntfs -3g tool. and they could be accessed through a file manager application.
But if I could find a way to format this partitions to ext4 from ntfs without losing the data, then the partition manager could easily read them.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no tool for converting a filesystem from NTFS to ext4 in place. You need to backup the data, create an ext4 filesystem, then restore the data to the ext4 filesystem. Or create an ext4 filesystem on a second storage device and copy the files there.